# SQL Server using pivot/unpivot in a new table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

Needless to say, I am trying to understand pivot/unpivot topic in the last few days with no hope. I do not understand what is pivot and what is unpivot. I have this table:
This table is called `Natalie_Playground`.

```
BuildingName    BillingMonth    Consumption

Building1       1/1/2011        59318

Building2       1/1/2011        6962

Building3       1/1/2011        204300

Building4       1/1/2011        69600

Building5       2/1/2011        47316

Building6       2/1/2011        162300

Building7       2/1/2011        7122

Building8       2/1/2011        7444
```

I do not know if I have to use pivot or unpivot to make my table looks like this:

```
BuildingName    January      February    March  .... December

Building1       59318        47316

Building2       6962         162300

Building3       204300       162300

Building4       69600        7444
```

Comment: Simply, PIVOT takes a value from a row and turns it into a column, UNPIVOT does the opposite, in this case PIVOT is what you're after.

Comment: Would you please show me the syntax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to use the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function to convert the rows of data into columns:

```
select buildingname, January, February, March, April
from
(
  select buildingname,
    datename(month, billingmonth) month,
    consumption
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  sum(consumption)
  for month in (January, February, March, April)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c935/3). The UNPIVOT function is used to take multiple columns and convert them into multiple rows of data.

Comment: Bluefeet you are my saver, thank you so much for your time. This is exactly what I am looking for.